# Enumerating attributes with DocumentTraversal

Tags: javascript, html, document, traversal

I need to enumerate elements attributes using DocumentTraversal. I'm targeting IE11 only. It works fine for elements, but I can't get it work with attributes. It stops at first one.

```
<div id ="div1" class="dd" style="background: yellow" rrr="rrtis">

var a0 = document.getElementById('div1').attributes[0];
var ni = document.createNodeIterator(a0, 0xffff, null, false);
var nn = ni.nextNode();
```

at this point nn is pointing to 'class' attribute

```
var nn1 = ni.nextNode();
```

nn1 is pointing to text node 'dd'.

```
var nn2 = ni.nextNode();
```

nn2 is pointing to 'null'.

So instead of
    id -> class -> style -> rrr
the tree is
    class -> 'dd'

http://jsfiddle.net/Bfumh/1/

I'm referring this doc - http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/traversal.html

Also it would be great to navigate from one attribute to another with treeWalker.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use iterators? Seems like this should be as simple as:

```
    var div = document.getElementById('div1');

    for (var idx = 0; idx < div.attributes.length; idx++) {
        var atr = div.attributes[idx];

        // If you want to make sure the attribute has a value,
        // include the following conditional. Otherwise just
        // use the `name` property.

        if (atr.specified) {
            console.log(atr.name + ': ' + atr.value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes I have. DocumentTraveral interface gives me extra text nodes with formatting preserved. And this works fine for elements, but doesn't for attributes.